# Problem running Grails after creating static scaffolding

Tags: java, spring, grails

**After I generate-all the views and controller I received these errors.Down below :**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'staffService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.grails.datastore.mapping.services.ServiceNotFoundException: No service found for type interface coffeeshop.StaffService
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:841)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:485)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:472)
at coffeeshop.Application.main(Application.groovy:11)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.grails.datastore.mapping.services.ServiceNotFoundException: No service found for type interface coffeeshop.StaffService
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.services.DefaultServiceRegistry.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.groovy:81)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractDatastore.getService(AbstractDatastore.java:102)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:280)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean.invokeWithTargetException(MethodInvokingBean.java:123)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.config.DatastoreServiceMethodInvokingFactoryBean.invokeWithTargetException(DatastoreServiceMethodInvokingFactoryBean.groovy:30)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1830)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767)
... 22 common frames omitted
```

**And here is the code in my controller:**
**I notice that the staff.label is in red**

package coffeeshop

import grails.validation.ValidationException
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*

class StaffController {

```
StaffService staffService

static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond staffService.list(params), model:[staffCount: staffService.count()]
}

def show(Long id) {
    respond staffService.get(id)
}

def create() {
    respond new Staff(params)
}

def save(Staff staff) {
    if (staff == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    try {
        staffService.save(staff)
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        respond staff.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'staff.label', default: 'Staff'), staff.id])
            redirect staff
        }
        '*' { respond staff, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}

def edit(Long id) {
    respond staffService.get(id)
}

def update(Staff staff) {
    if (staff == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    try {
        staffService.save(staff)
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        respond staff.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'staff.label', default: 'Staff'), staff.id])
            redirect staff
        }
        '*'{ respond staff, [status: OK] }
    }
}

def delete(Long id) {
    if (id == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    staffService.delete(id)

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'staff.label', default: 'Staff'), id])
            redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
    }
}

protected void notFound() {
    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'staff.label', default: 'Staff'), params.id])
            redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
    }
}
```

}

**Would really appreciate any help**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxkiP.png)

Comment: Can you show the source for `coffeeshop.StaffService.groovy`?

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and responding to my question Unfortunately I am new to grails framework. If you could point me out where to find the coffeeshop.StaffService.groovy it would be really helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: By default it would be under `grails-app/services/coffeeshop/StaffService.groovy`.

Comment: That files was not created.

Comment: "That files was not created" - If that is the case, that is a bug in our plugin.  If you verify that the service isn't being created when you generate scaffolding, if you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and report the version of Grails, OS, and JDK you are using, we can get that straightened out.